# не выводит данные JSON файла

Tags: java, android, json

коллеги!

Имею json файл:

```
[{"wrapperType":"track","kind":"song","artistId":1017136601,"collectionId":1051991020,"trackId":1051991441,"artistName":"Kiiara","collectionName":"Gold - Single","trackName":"Gold","collectionCensoredName":"Gold - Single","trackCensoredName":"Gold","artistViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/artist\/kiiara\/1017136601?uo=4","collectionViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/gold\/1051991020?i=1051991441\u0026uo=4","trackViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/gold\/1051991020?i=1051991441\u0026uo=4","previewUrl":"https:\/\/audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com\/itunes-assets\/Music6\/v4\/2b\/a5\/c8\/2ba5c86c-ca23-1f96-dd77-7bd9ad960a40\/mzaf_8477152025865893862.plus.aac.p.m4a","artworkUrl30":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music69\/v4\/37\/38\/0e\/37380e3d-24ef-004a-e129-c033a46ae3c0\/source\/30x30bb.jpg","artworkUrl60":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music69\/v4\/37\/38\/0e\/37380e3d-24ef-004a-e129-c033a46ae3c0\/source\/60x60bb.jpg","artworkUrl100":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music69\/v4\/37\/38\/0e\/37380e3d-24ef-004a-e129-c033a46ae3c0\/source\/100x100bb.jpg","collectionPrice":22,"trackPrice":22,"releaseDate":"2015-03-22T07:00:00Z","collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit","trackExplicitness":"notExplicit","discCount":1,"discNumber":1,"trackCount":1,"trackNumber":1,"trackTimeMillis":225882,"country":"RUS","currency":"RUB","primaryGenreName":"\u041f\u043e\u043f","isStreamable":true,"arCurSong_artistName":"Kiiara","arCurSong_trackName":"Gold"},{"artistName":"Meduza","trackName":"Lose Control","arCurSong_artistName":"Meduza","arCurSong_trackName":"Lose Control"},{"wrapperType":"track","kind":"song","artistId":64387566,"collectionId":1482965877,"trackId":1482965898,"artistName":"Katy Perry","collectionName":"Harleys in Hawaii - Single","trackName":"Harleys in Hawaii","collectionCensoredName":"Harleys in Hawaii - Single","trackCensoredName":"Harleys in Hawaii","artistViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/artist\/katy-perry\/64387566?uo=4","collectionViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/harleys-in-hawaii\/1482965877?i=1482965898\u0026uo=4","trackViewUrl":"https:\/\/music.apple.com\/ru\/album\/harleys-in-hawaii\/1482965877?i=1482965898\u0026uo=4","previewUrl":"https:\/\/audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com\/itunes-assets\/AudioPreview123\/v4\/80\/0a\/fa\/800afa07-7058-6fed-f8ea-58664561d773\/mzaf_6669635699190731554.plus.aac.p.m4a","artworkUrl30":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/53\/a0\/16\/53a016d9-f6d0-a42c-8fb6-967768de9254\/source\/30x30bb.jpg","artworkUrl60":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/53\/a0\/16\/53a016d9-f6d0-a42c-8fb6-967768de9254\/source\/60x60bb.jpg","artworkUrl100":"https:\/\/is4-ssl.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music123\/v4\/53\/a0\/16\/53a016d9-f6d0-a42c-8fb6-967768de9254\/source\/100x100bb.jpg","collectionPrice":22,"trackPrice":22,"releaseDate":"2019-10-16T07:00:00Z","collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit","trackExplicitness":"notExplicit","discCount":1,"discNumber":1,"trackCount":1,"trackNumber":1,"trackTimeMillis":185815,"country":"RUS","currency":"RUB","primaryGenreName":"\u041f\u043e\u043f","isStreamable":true,"arCurSong_artistName":"Katy Perry","arCurSong_trackName":"Harleys In Hawaii"}]
```

Код для его обработки использую:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.music);

        getResponse();
    }

    private void getResponse(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<String> call = api.getString();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() !=null) {
                        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                        writeMusic (jsonresponse);
                    } else {
                        Log.i("OnEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void writeMusic (String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

            ArrayList<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i<dataArray.length(); i++) {
                MusicModel musicModel = new MusicModel();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                musicModel.setArtistName(dataobj.getString("artistName"));
                musicModel.setTrackName(dataobj.getString("trackName"));

                musicModelArrayList.add(musicModel);
            }



            for (int j = 0; j < musicModelArrayList.size();j++){
                textView.setText(textView.getText()+musicModelArrayList.get(j).getArtistName()+ " " +musicModelArrayList.get(j).getTrackName());
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно, мыслю в правильном направлении - указал в строке в скобках значение "response":
JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray(response);

Верно ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Мысль условно-верная, но направление не удобное. Так как в итоге вы хотите получить список объектов модели, то проще будет использовать `GsonConverter`.
Добавить зависимость в build.gradle(module):

```
 // номер версии меняем на нужный/актуальный по необходимости
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
```

Тип запроса меняем на `List<MusicModel>`, для примера:

```
@Get("api/path")
public Call<List<MusicModel>> getMusic();
```

Запрос:

```
private void getResponse() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ApiInterface.JSONURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<MusicModel>> call = api.getMusic();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MusicModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Response<List<MusicModel>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList = response.body();
                if (musicModelArrayList != null) {
                    showMusicList(musicModelArrayList);
                } else {
                    Log.w("onResponse", "Returned empty response");
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("onResponse", "Not success response: " + response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Throwable t) {
             Log.e("Retrofit", "onFailure: ", t);
        }
    });
}

private void showMusicList(List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList) {
    textView.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", musicModelArrayList));
}
```

Модель (по желанию можно добавить поля, геттеры и сеттеры для других значений):

```
public class MusicModel {

    @SerializedName("artistName")
    @Expose
    private String artistName;
    @SerializedName("trackName")
    @Expose
    private String trackName;

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getTrackName() {
        return trackName;
    }

    public void setTrackName(String trackName) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return artistName + " - " + trackName;
    }
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю, модель формировали с ресурса:http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org?

Comment: Ок. Сейчас переделаю.

Comment: Последняя версия редакции кода оказалась верной. Спасибо. Теперь действительно отображается правильная строка. Осталась фича только с одной последней строкой, но, думаю, здесь можно просто обратиться к элементу массива.

Comment: С последней строкой проблем нет - это просто из-за цикла лишний перевод строки в конце. Можете заменить на `join` (см. в ответе). Только в модели надо переопределить `toString()`, чтобы возвращал нужную строку.

Comment: Я имел в виду (сейчас будет немного сложно :-)) последняя строка - это та, которая приходит последней в json файл. Т. е. она первая в нашем списке. Вот её, родную, и пытаюсь отобразить :-). Простым обращением к элементу массива это возможно?